# Microsoft Surface Mobile Mouse lags on Windows 10 Bootcamp

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, mouse, bluetooth, boot-camp

Just bought a Microsoft Surface Mobile Mouse to go with my macbook. I know this isn't a performance mouse, but the lag is unbearable in Windows 10 via bootcamp! However, it work ok on macOS Mojave.

The problem relates to joint use of bluetooth and wifi at the same time on 2.4GHZ frequency: in Windows10/bootcamp if I connect to a 5GHZ wifi network, the mouse works fine. But in a regular 2.4GHZ wifi network it lags badly.

Strange enough: on MacOS Mojave the mouse works well in both 2.4 and 5GHZ wifi connections.

Is there any way I can fix / make this bearable? Can't seem to update win10 drivers since bootcamp drivers are at their most updated state already.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: MacBook Pro Early 2015. Odd enough is that now it is working reasonably well, ie some minor glitches but bearable. Without any update. Will be keeping an eye to see if something else may be interfering. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Open Device Manager from the list of links on the left panel
> 2. Expand the Network adapters section to list your network adapters (e.g. WiFi, Bluetooth, VPN, etc.)
> 3. Double click your WiFi network adapter to open the Device Properties dialog (in my case this is a Dell Wireless 1830 802.11ac)
> 4. Switch to the Advanced tab (if you cannot see an Advanced tab then close this dialog and double click the other Network Adapters until you find one that has it)
>
>    1. Within the Property list, select Bluetooth Collaboration
>    2. Change the Value of the dropdown list from Auto to Disabled
>    3. Click OK to save changes

Copied from: [Fix for Stuttering and Lag in BT Mouse on Windows 10](https://visser.io/2016/04/fix-for-stuttering-lag-in-bluetooth-mouse-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion. Unfortunately I cant't test it since I switched to a Microsoft Precision BT Mouse which works fine out of the box.